# Chaining multiple predicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a some filters that chains around 30 `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` using `linq to entities`. Currently this is how I am managing them

```
        ...
        //project filter
        Expression<Func<Project, bool>> projectFilter = FilterEnabled();
        projectFilter = projectFilter.And(GetProjectByOrganization())
             .And(GetProjectByProductLine())
             .And(GetProjectByProjectType())
        ...

        //subproject filter
        Expression<Func<SubProject, bool>> subProjectFilter = FilterEnabled();
        subProjectFilter = subProjectFilter .And(...)
        ...

        //activity filter
        Expression<Func<Activity, bool>> activityFilter = FilterEnabled();
        activityFilter = activityFilter .And(...)
        ...
```

The problem is `.And(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)` extension method goes on for another 30 lines or so. How can I manage this another way instead of having to add `.And` 30+ times for each filter critera. Each filter method looks something like this.

```
public Expression<Func<Project, bool>> GetProjectByProjectId()
{
    return prj => FilterCriteria.ProjectId == null || prj.ProjectID == FilterCriteria.ProjectId.Value;
}
```

This is also my predicate builder class where I created the `.And()`

```
 public static class PredicateBuilder
    {

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> a, Expression<Func<T, bool>> b)
        {
            ParameterExpression p = a.Parameters[0];

            SubstExpressionVisitor visitor = new SubstExpressionVisitor();
            visitor.subst[b.Parameters[0]] = p;

            Expression body = Expression.And(a.Body, visitor.Visit(b.Body));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> a, Expression<Func<T, bool>> b)
        {
            ParameterExpression p = a.Parameters[0];

            SubstExpressionVisitor visitor = new SubstExpressionVisitor();
            visitor.subst[b.Parameters[0]] = p;

            Expression body = Expression.Or(a.Body, visitor.Visit(b.Body));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
        }
    }


    internal class SubstExpressionVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public Dictionary<Expression, Expression> subst = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            Expression newValue;
            if (subst.TryGetValue(node, out newValue))
            {
                return newValue;
            }
            return node;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is performance a concern? I can easily see that becoming a heavy operation.

Comment: @Denis No it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the direct question, the obvious way is to have an `All` method which takes a `params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] expressions` argument. You'll still have a 30-line call, but you won't have `And` on each line. There are potential side-benefits:

- It should reduce the amount of wrapping an expression just to unwrap it immediately.
- If you decide that you want `AndAlso` instead of `And` (is there any reason for not using it?) then it's much simpler to change.

---

I would also be tempted to favour a refactor which allows `null` expressions. If instead of

> ```
> public Expression<Func<Project, bool>> GetProjectByProjectId()
> {
>     return prj => FilterCriteria.ProjectId == null || prj.ProjectID == FilterCriteria.ProjectId.Value;
> }
> ```

you have

```
public Expression<Func<Project, bool>> GetProjectByProjectId()
{
    return FilterCriteria.ProjectId == null ? null : (prj => prj.ProjectID == FilterCriteria.ProjectId.Value);
}
```

(with whatever type coercion is necessary to make that compile - I haven't tested it) then you can filter out null expressions in `All`. This both simplifies the expression constructed and the SQL generated from it, which might improve performance and might also make debugging it easier.

---

Finally, two comments about `SubstExpressionVisitor:`

> ```
>     public Dictionary<Expression, Expression> subst = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();
> ```

On the basis of coding to the interface rather than the implementation, the type should be `IDictionary<Expression, Expression>`. I personally would also prefer to hide the field and take the substitutions as arguments to the constructor rather than by modifying a public field after construction, but that's a subjective issue of style. If making that change, the type can become `IReadOnlyDictionary<Expression, Expression>` instead.

> ```
>     protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
>     {
>         Expression newValue;
>         if (subst.TryGetValue(node, out newValue))
>         {
>             return newValue;
>         }
>         return node;
>     }
> ```

Too many people use `Contains` and then `[key]` rather than `TryGetValue`, so thumbs up for getting that right. I would observe, though, that `foo.TryGetValue(key, out val) ? val : defaultVal` is a common enough pattern that you could consider factoring it out as an extension method to `IDictionary<K,V>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>`.